# How do you re locate a tap-target button using the materialize css?

Tags: css, materialize

Does anyone have a useful solution to moving a tap-target button from the bottom right hand corner of the screen? I can move any other btn class around on the page besides this. I have tried using margin, padding, even surrounding it in a outer div and moving the div around. Is this possible using materialize?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") should include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This codepen (which is not mine) shows a [Materialize tap-target](https://materializecss.com/feature-discovery.html) in a different location:

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/mrIT/pen/zaqoyP)

The tap-target default, and many examples, uses a [fixed-action-btn](https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html) class.  Change the fixed class to one that allows you to place the component where you want on the page.

Here is an example:

```
    <div class="left">
    <!--<div class="fixed-action-btn">-->
      <a id="menu" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-floating">o</a>
```